# How to formulate a regex to get Dates from specific strings?

Tags: c#, regex, datetime, substitution

i have the following strings:

> Months:
>   Jan11
>   Feb11
>   Mar11
>   Apr11
>   etc.
>   Quarters:
>   Q1 11
>   Q2 11
>   Q3 11
>   Q4 11
>   Q1 12
>   etc.
>   Years
>   Cal_11
>   Cal_12
>   Cal_13
>   etc.

I would like to use a regular expression to create a DateTime object starting at the beginning of each date represented by a string. So Jan11 would be

```
new DateTime(2011,1,1)
```

, Q2 11 would be

```
new DateTime(2011,4,1)
```

and Cal_12 would be

```
new DateTime(2012,1,1).
```

Comment: Out of interest -- why a regex? Could you maintain some small dictionaries of name -> value mappings to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should take of all three cases:

```
DateTime? parse(string text)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(text, @"^(\w\w\w)(\d+)$");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        return new DateTime(
            2000 + Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value), 
            1 + Array.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames, m.Groups[1].Value), 
            1);
    }

    m = Regex.Match(text, @"^Q(\d+) (\d+)$");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        return new DateTime(
            2000 + Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value), 
            1 + 3 * (Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value) - 1), 
            1);
    }

    m = Regex.Match(text, @"^Cal_(\d+)$");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        return new DateTime(
            2000 + Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value),
            1,
            1);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Calling like this:

```
parse("Jan11");
parse("Q2 11");
parse("Cal_12");
```

Please note that this doesn't account for incorrect data passed in.  This could be added obviously, but would make the example quite cluttered.